# StreamReader read by char encoding

Tags: c#, .net, encoding

I need to read text file with ASCII encoding char by char. If i have in that file aposthrope(’) character then i get questionmark instead. I checked if the file is in ASCII and it is so there won't be problem.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(this.path, Encoding.ASCII);

while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    char chr = (char) reader.Read();
    // if i read character ’ then the content of chr is: 63 '?'
    // but i need aposthrope not questionmark

}
```

Comment: This code works fine. Probably your file is not in ASCII

Comment: Use a Hex editor to make sure that the ' is really in your file as 29x (39)!

Comment: @TaW Problem resolved - that char was in fact some different char. I should have check it twice.

Comment: You can always manually change it if you want to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your source must be saved in a different encoding format. If you want to change the question mark(63) to an apostrophe(39) all you have to do is modify your code like so

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(this.path, Encoding.ASCII);
int c = 0;
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    c=reader.Read()
    char chr = c==63?(char)39:(char)c;
}
```

Learn something new: `? : :` is the ternary operator and is a very nice shorthand for something like this.

> (check condition)?(result if true):(result if false)